# Where to store Record meta data with Redux and Immutable JS

Tags: redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I switched over to a Redux + Immutable JS project from Ember a few months ago and am overall enjoying the experience.

One problem I *still* have not found a nice solution for when working with Records is storing meta data for that Record.

For example, let's say I have a `User` record:

```
const userRecord = Immutable.Record({
    id: null,
    name: '',
    email: ''
});
```

For the `User`, I may also wish to store properties like `isLoading` or `isSaved`. The first solution would be to store these in the `userRecord`. Although this would be the easiest solution by far, this feels wrong to me.

Another solution might be to create a `User` Map, which contains the `User` Record, as well as meta data about the User.

Ex.

```
const userMap = Immutable.Map({
    record: Immutable.Record({
        id: null,
        name: '',
        email: ''
    }),
    isLoading: false,
    isSaved: true
});
```

I think this is more elegant, but I don't like how all the user properties become even more deeply nested, so accessing User properties becomes very verbose.

What I miss most about Ember is being able to access Model properties easily.

Ex. `user.get('isSaved')` or `user.get('name')`

Is it possible to recreate something like this with Redux and Immutable? How have you approached this situation before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding the problem, because

> What I miss most about Ember is being able to access Model properties easily.
>
> user.get('isSaved') or user.get('name')

This *does* work for Immutable records.

If you don't want to add too many properties to your record, you could have a single status property and add some getters (assuming your statuses are mutually exclusive):

```
const STATUS = {
  INITIAL: 'INITIAL',
  LOADING: 'LOADING',
  SAVING: 'SAVING
};

class UserRecord extends Immutable.Record({
  id: null, 
  name: '', 
  email: '', 
  status: STATUS.INITIAL}) {

  isLoading() {
    return this.get('status') === STATUS.LOADING;
  }

  isSaving() {
    return this.get('status') === STATUS.SAVING;
  }
}

new UserRecord().isLoading());  // returns false

new UserRecord({status: STATUS.LOADING}).isLoading();  // returns true
new UserRecord().set('status', STATUS.LOADING).isLoading();  // returns true
```

Comment: _Exactly_ what I was looking for. Thank you!